# sample standard deviation given population standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

How do you find the sample standard deviation when given the population standard deviation? What formula do you use? If you can make up an example that would be great.

Comment: In order to get the sample standard deviation, you need a sample.

Comment: I have added a bit more information maybe it will be usefull

Comment: So what you wrote in your first sentence ("given the population standard deviation and no other data") is incorrect, as there is other data.

Comment: ok so do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: You must provide ***all relevant information***, always, in every post.

Comment: Note that you are being asked for the standard deviation of the *sample mean*, and *not* the sample standard deviation.  You need to study random variables and sample statistics.  Are you familiar with these?

Comment: I will be honest with you the second part of the question I copy pasted from another question, which is irrelevant according to you. All I want to know is how to get the sample standard deviation when given a population standard deviation, even an estimate. Is this possible or what would be needed to complete this?

Comment: You cannot get the sample standard deviation if you do not have the sample.  However, you *can* get the standard deviation of a *sample mean* even if you do not have the sample.  Again, you need to understand what random variables and sample statistics are.

Comment: @RobertB That's not what was said. Don't misconstrue people's comments.

Comment: can you give me an example? just make up a sample and show me how it would be done if you had the necessary information

Comment: Do you want an example of how to get a sample standard deviation if the only information you have is the population standard deviation?  No one can give you one because it is impossible.  You cannot get the sample standard deviation if you do not have a sample.

Comment: like I said I understand that, can you make up the necessary information and give me an example? because that is all I have to work with

Comment: Please be specific.  You want me to give you an example of what?

Comment: an example of finding the sample standard deviation from the population standard deviation. I understand that you need more information but that is all I have please just make up the rest of the information for the example and show me how it is done.

Comment: If your sample data is $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ then the sam[ple standard deviation, $\sigma$  is given by $\sigma^2=\sum \frac {(x_i-\overline x)^2}{n-1}$.  Note the $n-1$ instead of $n$ in the denominator.  The true standard deviation is irrelevant.

Comment: This question took a completely wrong turn. I understand how to get the sample standard deviation, my problem is that I need to get the sample standard deviation given the population standard deviation which is possible according to the person that asked me this question. Can you just tell me how that would be possible and what other information would be needed? I understand that they can be found separately and I understand that what I have written may not be enough information but that is all I have to work with.

Comment: I think you better seek clarification from the person who asked you.  I suspect that that person is thinking of the standard deviation of the sample mean (and not of the sample standard deviation).  If so, then see the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**My answer based on the second version of the original post:**

According to the central limit theorem, the standard deviation of the sample mean of $n$ data from a population is $\sigma_{\overline{X}}=\sigma_X/\sqrt{n}$, where $\sigma_X$ is the population standard deviation.  In your case, $\sigma_{\overline{X}}=40/\sqrt{100}=4$.

**My answer based on the first and third versions of the original post:**

In order to "get the sample standard deviation," you need to specify a sample (a subset of the population).  If you do not specify a sample, then you cannot get the sample standard deviation.  If you do specify the sample, then you can get the sample standard deviation.  In either case, knowledge of the population standard deviation is irrelevant.

For example, consider a population $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,k\}$ where $k$ is, say, some integer greater than 3.  Even if I told you what the population standard deviation was, there is still no way to find the sample standard deviation because no sample was specified.

Now consider a sample $\{0,1,2\}$.  The sample mean is $(0+1+2)/3=1$, the sample variance is $s_X^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x})^2=\frac{1}{3-1}[(0-1)^2+(1-1)^2+(2-1)^2]=1$, and the sample standard deviation is $s_X=1$, regardless of what the population standard deviation is.

Comment: @Robert B note that this is the standard error of the sample mean (a measure of variations in the sample mean that you would observe if you repeatedly took 100 observations). This is different from the sample standard deviation (which measures the variation of all observations in the sample)

Comment: I understand that now, I edited the question because it was creating confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The simple formula is Square the sample standard deviation, then multiple the value with (Total number of Samples/Sample - 1)

N- number of samples

P.SD = sqrt[ (S.SD * S.SD) (N/N- 1))

Ex : Standard Deviation of a data is 6.621124203 with 8 samples

Population Deviation would be = Sqrt[ (6.621 * 6.621) (7/8) ]

=Sqrt[(43.837641)(0.875)]

=Sqrt[38.357935875]

= 6.19337838945757

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AucWo.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. Please use latex also in this website.